# Hypothesis Testing Question (Poisson Random Variable)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, poisson-distribution, hypothesis-testing

$\text{The question:}$ A new web page design is intended to increase the rate at which customers place orders. Prior to the new design, the number of orders in an hour was a Poisson random variable with mean $\lambda=30$. Eight one-hour measurements with the new design find an average 32 orders completed per hour.

a) At a $5\%$ significance level, do the data support the claim that the order placement has increased?
b) For $1\%$?

$\text{My Solution:}$ We model this Poisson random variable as a Gaussian (with variance being equal to $\lambda$), so:
$$\alpha = 0.05 = P(\hat{X}_8>30+c)$$
$$P\Bigg[\frac{\hat{X}_{8}-30}{\sqrt{\frac{30}{8}}}>\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{30}{8}}}\Bigg]=Q\Bigg[\frac{c}{\sqrt{\frac{30}{8}}}\Bigg]$$
$$\implies c= Q^{-1}(0.05)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{30}{8}}\approx3.18$$
Now, since $32<33.18$, we can't reject the null hypothesis that the mean is $30$.

Now with $\alpha=0.01$ we get $c= Q^{-1}(0.01)\cdot\sqrt{\frac{30}{8}}\approx4.496$, which yields the same conclusion as before: the null hypothesis can't be rejected.  Is this just a dumb question setup, and I did it right? It seems strange that $a)$ and $b)$ would give the same answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be easier to consider lambda = 240 for the 8 hours and work from there. The variance would be 240, the standard deviation about 15.5, and the new sales number 256, just over 1 SD higher. Which isn't enough to meet either criteria.

Comment: If you fail to reject at the 5% level than you must fail to reject at the 1% level. Nothing strange about that.

Answer (score 0):

Exact Poisson computation: If $X \sim Pois(240),$ then what is $P(X \ge 256).$
This is the P-value of your test of $H_0: \lambda = 240$ against
$H_a: \lambda > 240.$ Notice that (per @barrycarter) everything has been re-scaled to an 8-hour period.

The answer from R statistical software is that
$P(X \ge 256) \approx 0.15,$ so we do not reject at any level below 15%.
In particular, no rejection at 5% or 1% level. Simply put, an average of 32 orders per hour over an 8-hour period would not be really surprising if the
true Poisson rate were still 30 per hour.

```
 1 - ppois(255, 240)  # in R, 'ppois' is the Poisson CDF
 ## 0.1584904
```

Because it is easy to get an exact Poisson probability using software, it
is not really necessary to use a normal approximation. However, in case the
point of your exercise is drill using the normal distribution, then it goes like this:

$$P(X \ge 256) \approx P\left(Z \ge \frac{256 - 240}{\sqrt{240}} = 1.033 \right) \approx 0.151,$$

where the first approximation sign is because of the normal approximation
to the binomial and the second is for approximations in evaluating the normal
probability. (If you use printed normal tables, you may get a slightly different answer.) Generally speaking, one cannot expect better than about
two place accuracy using a normal approximation to a Poisson distribution.

Comment: Continuity correction on the normal approximation yields a closer result, about $0.158529$.

Comment: @heropup: Yes indeed. And possibly relevant, if you believe the average '30' means 30.00, so that the number of sales was exactly 256 instead of, say 254 or 257.